# Pyspark - Indicate missing JSON field with something other than null

Tags: json, null, apache-spark-sql, missing-data

I am using an output of [Maxwell's Daemon](http://maxwells-daemon.io/) to capture changes that happened on a MySQL database. It indicates changes as nested JSON fields: 'data' contains the latest snapshot of the table and 'old' indicates the fields that changed.

When I read this JSON into a Spark DataFrame, all the missing fields of 'old' are set to 'null'.

**This is an unfortunate situation, because I don't have a way of telling if the field changed from 'null' to '[some_value]', or some other field changed for the row and the 'null' represents the missing field in the JSON.**

Here is an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, BooleanType, LongType

custom_schema = StructType(
[StructField("type", StringType(), True),
 StructField("ts", LongType(), True),
 StructField("xid", LongType(), True),
 StructField("data", StructType([
     StructField("id", LongType(), True),
     StructField("bought_by", StringType(), True),
     StructField("userprofile_id", StringType(), True)]), True),
 StructField("old", StructType([
     StructField("id", LongType(), True),
     StructField("bought_by", StringType(), True),
     StructField("userprofile_id", StringType(), True)]), True)]
)

source_list = [
'{"type":"update","ts":1510901244,"xid":1,"data":{"id":1,"bought_by":"user:1","userprofile_id":1}, "old":{"userprofile_id":null}}', 
'{"type":"update","ts":1510901245,"xid":2,"data":{"id":1,"bought_by":"user:1","userprofile_id":null}, "old":{"userprofile_id":2}}',
'{"type":"update","ts":1510901246,"xid":3,"data":{"id":1,"bought_by":"user:1","userprofile_id":1}, "old":{"userprofile_id":2}}',
'{"type":"update","ts":1510901246,"xid":4,"data":{"id":1,"bought_by":"user:1","userprofile_id":1}, "old":{"bought_by":"user:2"}}',
]

df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(source_list), schema=custom_schema)

df.show()
```

The output of this is:

```
+------+----------+---+---------------+------------------+
|  type|        ts|xid|           data|               old|
+------+----------+---+---------------+------------------+
|update|1510901244|  1|   [1,user:1,1]|  [null,null,null]|
|update|1510901245|  2|[1,user:1,null]|     [null,null,2]|
|update|1510901246|  3|   [1,user:1,1]|     [null,null,2]|
|update|1510901246|  4|   [1,user:1,1]|[null,user:2,null]|
+------+----------+---+---------------+------------------+
```

However I am looking to produce something like this:

```
+------+----------+---+---------------+--------------------+
|  type|        ts|xid|           data|                 old|
+------+----------+---+---------------+--------------------+
|update|1510901244|  1|   [1,user:1,1]|  ['N/A','N/A',null]|
|update|1510901245|  2|[1,user:1,null]|     ['N/A','N/A',2]|
|update|1510901246|  3|   [1,user:1,1]|     ['N/A','N/A',2]|
|update|1510901246|  4|   [1,user:1,1]|['N/A',user:2,'N/A']|
+------+----------+---+---------------+--------------------+
```

I have spent quite some time searching for a solution, but I only found articles that were explaining of this situation with 'null' values representing the missing fields, and solutions that would replace all 'null' values with some other value, but none of those help in my situation.

**The closest solution right now I have is this:**

Since we are ingesting the data using Gobblin, we would add a rule to replace

> "userprofile_id":null with "userprofile_id":-1

or for string values replace

> "string_field":null with "string_field":"N/A"

**But it is way too hacky to be scalable.**

Any help for solving this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I got an ugly solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47531436/8432213 and still waiting for a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reading in the source file as RDD, doing a string replacement for the 'null' fields that I wanted to identify (with a default value), writing out the result to a temp location and reading back the stuff as a DataFrame. Then I am handling the default values as Null later in my code. This is very ugly, but it works.

```
NULL_USERPROFILE_ID = -1234321

in_file = spark.sparkContext.textFile(source + "*")
rdd = in_file.map(lambda x: x.replace('"userprofile_id":null', '"userprofile_id":%d' % NULL_USERPROFILE_ID))
rdd.saveAsTextFile(destination)
```

I would be happy to refactor it, if I get a clue how to assign a default value to a missing JSON field when reading it into DataFrame.